# When do you need to pass the name of your element to the main Polymer function?

Tags: polymer

When defining custom elements, the [API developer guide](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html) always passes the name of the custom element as the first argument to the `Polymer()` function.

```
Polymer('my-element', {/*stuff*/});
```

In the [Tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html), however, the `Polymer()` function is consistently called without the name and simply passed the prototype object.

```
Polymer({/*stuff*/});
```

As the `Polymer()` function doesn't seem to be explicitly defined anywhere in the documentation I was just wondering what the recommendation is. Are there any pitfalls to leaving the name out or should you always pass it just to be safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the name argument to `Polymer()` iff:

1. your definition is in an import
2. the `<script>` node containing the `Polymer()` call is inside the matching `<polymer-element>` node

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should always declare the name of your polymer-element to make your code more readable, at least for others.

Nevertheless, it looks like you can skip the name and let Polymer do the detection. If I get it right Polymer looks for the name attribute of its first parent node.

> https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-dev/blob/master/src/declaration/polymer.js#L20-29

I tried it on `https://ele.io` and it worked for me.

Comment: +1 for the link. As you said it looks like they check for the name property of the script's parent node.